# How to upload products from one Prestashop store to another Prestashop store?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

We have two prestashop domains for example abc.com and xyz.com with separate databases. We want upload the products from one Prestashop store to another prestashop store. As all we know all the product images will be stored in img folder of prestashop. Now we want to use these images from store 1 and upload to store 2 img folder and synchronize only product related data from the database 1 to database 2.

Kindly provide your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I found some migration free module that allows you can transfer a part of data on your site.

You can research an use these. I had transferred product and categories form the old site to another site by [Upgrade PrestaShop free](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/820013-migrate-or-upgrade-prestashop-16-or-other-versions-to-17-%E2%80%93-free-module/)

If you need to migrate more data or all of the data, just purchase [1 CLICK to migrate](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/837697-1-click-migrate-or-upgrade-to-prestashop-17/)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same task of copying data from one database to another for managing products on two identical sites. My sites are completely identical.

1. One option is to have multishop feature on and than have two sites in the same back office with same products, features and images. It is very convenient for more than one shop management.
2. Second option is if you don't want a multishop option than you can export ps_product_shop, ps_image, ps_product, ps_product_lang tables and than use 'INSERT' statements if products are not existing in new location or 'REPLACE' statements if products are already there.

Other tables that may require changing are ps_product_sale (if you want sales of the products to be copied as well) and ps_product_supplier(suppliers data), ps_stock_available(for available stock for the products) depending on your requirements.

Make sure you do 'REPLACE INTO' instead of 'INSERT INTO' if you are not sure if the product is being duplicated or not.

Something like this

```
LOCK TABLES `ps_product_shop` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `ps_product_shop` DISABLE KEYS */;
REPLACE INTO `ps_product_shop` VALUES (1000010,1,1112,-------------------
………………………………………………
………………………………………………………………………………
…………………………………………………………
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `ps_product_shop` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Since my sites are same, i simply replace the p folder in (/img/p) with new p folder from my other site. (Or rename the old p folder to p_old and place the new p folder there.) This works fine for me, I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried [this tool (Store Manager for PrestaShop)](https://www.prestashopmanager.com/useful-articles/how-to/how-to-transfer-prestashop-database-to-another-store/) for PrestaShop data transfer (categories, products, customers) via the export/import option. It is not difficult in usage and saved some time and you can use it for free for a couple of days. Moreover, it has a possibility to automate export and import.